Salesforce CLI update fails
For some reason, sfdx update isn't working on my laptop.  No matter what I do, I always get the following error:
C:\Users\Some.User>sfdx update
@salesforce/cli: Updating CLI from 2.63.8 to 2.63.8-fbf82e0... !
    Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename
    'C:\Users\Some.User\AppData\Local\sf\client\2.63.8-fbf82e0.partial.45442\sf' ->
    'C:\Users\Some.User\AppData\Local\sf\client\2.63.8-fbf82e0'
    Code: EPERM

I tried running the following:

Execute the update within a Command Prompt running as Administrator
Uninstalled the existing CLI and reinstalled it using sf-x64.exe

What's interesting is that I can install the CLI from scratch, but not update it.
The paths the process fails on don't exist before the update is performed, so I'm not sure if this is due to antivirus software running in the background.
Any advice would be appreciated!

Try
sf update
If you have installed using npm you will have to run:
"npm update --global @salesforce/cli"
